# How to use Terraform to create AWS infrastructure with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I'm setting a deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps for AWS infrastructure. I was wondering if there is an extension that will allow running Terraform scripts.

So far I was able to find how to do it for Azure only (the extension seems to allow authentication for Azure only).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a new Terraform extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks) by Microsoft (released on 26.7.2019) that supports AWS (and also Azure & GCP).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

> How to use Terraform to create AWS infrastructure with AzureDevOps

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such Terraform extension we could use to create AWS infrastructure with AzureDevOps.

Just like as you found, it seems those Terraform extension are integrated with Azure, like [Terraform Build & Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform&targetId=c519b80d-5d71-46b3-a8e0-3edf8c026ea2):

[image]

If it is important to you, you can open a [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) here:

[image]

You can vote and add your comments for this feedback. When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this helps.